# How to set the bottom margin in latex to be precisely what was declared by the geometry package

Tags: margins

I set the page margins by writing this code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 left=1in, 
 right=1in, 
 top=1.3in, 
 bottom=0.9in
]{geometry}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=100
```

I need to the bottom margin to be exactly 0.9in including the footnotes (no more no less). But, unfortunately, the bottom of some pages in my book exceeds the value 0.9in as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I fix this problem ?!.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Are you using `\flushbottom` ? Sometimes display math extends pass the bottom margin.

Comment: Not the issue on the page shown but your page size is not a multiple of baselineskip+topskip so a page with just text can not achieve  the bottom margin except to the nearest multipl of lines, and if you use `\flushbottom` such pages will always be underfull and short.

Comment: Add `showframe` to the geometry options to see the actual text area.  Also, `nofoot` will change the definition of bottom margin wrt the footer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Excuse me @DavidCarlisle
Can you teach me how to make my page size a multiple of baselineskip+topskip ?!. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HusseinEid see `heightrounded` option of `geometry`